# Java classes, JTable, JInternalFrame, JFrame

Tags: java, swing, class, jtable

I have a working code that adds a JTable to a JInternalFrame.
Then I add the JInternalFrame to a JFrame and I call it from a JMenu.
My issue is as follows: I'm trying to make the JTable nicer, so I would like to be able to make a separate class and do some things there and then add it to the JInternalFrame. It should work, but it doesn't and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. 
Here's the classes, trimmed down as much as possible:

```
public class AppLaunch {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    System.out.println("test");
                    ExternalFrame frm = new ExternalFrame("test me");
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

/* ----- */

import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MyTable extends JTable{
    private String[][] data;
    private String[] cols;
    MyTable(String[][] data, String[] cols){
        this.data = data;
        this.cols = cols;
    }
}

/* ----- */

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;

    private  MyTable myTable;
    private JTable jT;

    private JScrollPane scroll; 

    public MyInternalFrame(String title) {
        super("Document #" + title + (++openFrameCount), 
              true, //resizable
              true, //closable
              true, //maximizable
              true);//iconifiable

        setSize(300,300);
        setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);

        createTable();

        setContentPane(scroll); 

    }

    public void createTable(){
        String[][] data = {{"Hello", "Hello", "Hello"},{"Hello", "Hello", "Hello"}};
        String[] cols = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"};
        jT = new JTable(data, cols);
        myTable = new MyTable(data, cols);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(jT);
        //scroll = new JScrollPane(myTable);
    }
}

/* ----- */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class ExternalFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JDesktopPane desktop;

    private JMenuBar topMenu;

    private JMenu menuTables;
    private JMenuItem itemContact;
    private JMenuItem itemAddress;

    public ExternalFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); 
        setContentPane(desktop);
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
        System.out.println("JFrame Constructor\n");
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if(source == itemAddress) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Not implemented\n");
    }
    else if(source == itemContact) {
            createFrame("Contacts");
            System.out.println("Action Performed Create JInternalFrame\n");
    }
    }
    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        topMenu = new JMenuBar();

        menuTables = new JMenu("Tables");
        menuTables.setMnemonic('T');

        itemContact = new JMenuItem("Contact", 'C');
        itemAddress = new JMenuItem("Address", 'A');

        itemAddress.addActionListener(this);
        itemContact.addActionListener(this);


        menuTables.add(itemContact);
        menuTables.add(itemAddress);
        topMenu.add(menuTables);

        return topMenu;
    }
    protected void createFrame(String title) {
        MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame(title);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        System.out.println("Create frame\n");
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } 
        catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
    }

}

/* ----- */
```

Obviously this one here works :

```
    jT = new JTable(data, cols);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(jT);
```

However, the other one doesn't :

```
    myTable = new MyTable(data, cols);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(jT);
```

So I did something wrong with the `myTable` class, something silly I'm sure, but I just can't see it. 
At the end of it I want the table to get its data from a either MySql or SQL Server and I can't even move it to another file.

Comment: Well, your MyTable constructor implicitly calls the no-argument JTable constructor. So your table won't display the columns and the data that you pass as arguments. You shouldn't be extending JTable in the first place. Why do you think this is useful?

Comment: So I should just go ahead and do my ```MyModelTable``` extends ```AbstractModelTable``` and populate the JTable. I'll do it and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: @JB Nizet Just wanted to let you know that it worked. Kind of long to post everything here, but I ditched the MyTable and have my JTable constructed with 2 Vectors and it worked. Thanks again :)